# How does 'sending eyelashes' mean married?

Tags: idioms

In episode 12, season 2 of the series "friends", there is a letter for Joey from a woman. In the P.S. she wrote:

> P.S. Enclosed, please find 14 of my eyelashes.

From this they deduced that the sender is married.

> RACHEL: Ya know, in crazy world, that means you're married.

From what I found in my search, I can say that sending a lock of hair to someone is showing love to that person. But how does this mean being married?

EDIT:
Here is the [full transcript](http://friends.tktv.net/Episodes2/summaries/12-13.html). Please read the scene right after the "**OPENING TITLES**".

Comment: Maybe [this will help you](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/14-eyelashes-means-youre-married.2720331/) and you have to keep in mind that Erica (played by Brooke Shields) is [delusional](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnwJnorZ7Kw&t=0m13s)

Comment: From the link supplied by @Pet it seems the conclusion was that the sender and receiver were deemed "married" because the "crazy" sender sent some perversion of a lock of hair, a traditional sign of love. As it stands, the question contains insufficient context, and "sending eyelashes" is not an idiom.

Comment: Please provide a link to the script of the episode. This way we won't have to do your work for you. Otherwise, your question shows more research effort than many that are posted here. It is also an interesting question. It might be better on SE: English or SE: TV (if there is one), but a learner wouldn't know that.

Comment: Don't forget that Friends is a comedy and that, if I remember rightly, Joey is the stupid one. You might as well try to analyse Mork and Mindy, just laugh and ignore it.

Comment: I have added a link to the transcript.

Comment: The allusion is a parallelism to the before cited "lock of hair" which is the tradition romantic gesture. Rachel is just "mouthing off" (which she does often) and taking a jab at Joey (which she does often) since everyone knows Joey will never get married and Joey began the scene being so proud of his first fan mail.  No one has deduced whether the sender is married or not, it's just Rachel having a laugh at Joey's expense.

Comment: @Peter "No one has deduced whether the sender is married or not." That explains it, thanks. Unfortunately the question is on hold so you can't add an answer and I can't accept it but thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erica is obsessive and more than a little crazy.

She does something that is crazy (for comic effect), Rachel's joke is that "in a crazy world" if you give someone 14 eyelashes that makes you married to them. She is saying this to make fun of Joey, by telling him that Erica now thinks that they are married.

There is a tradition of "wishing on an eyelash" When an eyelash falls out you can [make a wish](https://xkcd.com/1086/).

There was a tradition (now mostly lost) of giving a [lock](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lock#Noun_2) of hair to a beloved, especially to soldiers before they left for war. This is comically changed to eyelashes.